# Unable to delete post_perf_fw.dll file when upgrading or performing a rollback

Tags: sql-server, windows, dll

When performing an upgrade or doing a rollback on our software, the following error is thrown:

> Unable to delete file "C:\Program Files......\System32\post_perf_fw.dll

When attempting to manually delete the file it complains with this error:

> The action can't be completed because the file is open in SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)

Windows 2012 SQL 2014 are present.

Note that this issue has occurred on Windows 8.1 Pro and Windows Server 2012. This also happened when Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP1 and SP2 was installed, although as of 07 Sep 2016 the machine with sql server 2012 with sp2 sql server installed has not been able to replicate this issue - it is unclear why.

Any ideas on why Microsoft will load this file, and how to overcome this problem?

Comment: what are you doing exactly `When performing an upgrade or doing a rollback on our software,`

Comment: The 'post_perf_fw.dll' is present in 2 directories, the software folder in 'Program Files', and the Windows directory. 
When upgrading/doing a rollback, the file is first deleted from the Windows directory and then copied from the software folder to the Windows directory. The file is then deleted from the software folder.
The 'Unable to delete' error is displayed when deleting from both folders. When attempting to manually delete the file, it complains that file is open in SQL Server. Stopping Sql Server allows for the handle to be released.

Comment: The dll file is used to load the performance counters for our software. How is SQL Server able to locate and load this file?